# InDesign: how to apply styles to specific words/phrases

Tags: adobe-indesign, formatting, grep

Is it possible to change the font style of specific phrases within an .indd document? I have several phrases to update in a giantic wall of text and all I need to do is change the font to a cursive. Be mindful that some parts of text have different font sizes and other styles.

Answer (score 3):

An automated way is to use [GREP Styles](http://blogs.adobe.com/indesignpost/2010/11/quick-tip-automatic-formatting-using-grep-styles-in-adobe-indesign/) via the Paragraph Style options. This feature is automatic so every time the phrase appears it will instantly apply the formatting without any manual search needed. A Character Style will need to be defined and then this will apply as a rule within your Paragraph Style.

If you're using multiple styles, you need to do this for each one.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found out how to do that:

1. Press Cmd/Ctrl-F and type in the phrase you wish to change.
2. Then select "more options" to show the format changing options and select w/e formatting you need for that specific phrase.